# how to allow my own google drive app to only upload files

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to develop a backup app, I wish that the app will be able only to upload files without any permissions to delete files (or any other permission).
is it possible ?

Comment: The generic answer will be yes, which is probably not what you wanted to hear.  Can you rephrase the question so it reflects something people can assist you with?

Comment: I currently have python code that upload files to my own drive. I with that with this code it will not be possible to delete files in my drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Start by looking for a python library that lets you communicate with the Google Drive API. See [Google APIs Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) and [PyDrive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive) (you'll find easy code as example here).